# Style svg root element inside html page

Tags: html, css, svg

In a svg document I can assign a background color to svg root element with something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     version="1.1"
     width="100%" height="100%">
<style>
   :root {
      background: blue;
   }
</style>
<circle cx="50%" cy="50% r="25%" fill="orange">
</svg>
```

But when the svg is inserted inside a html page :root refers to the html tag, not the svg root element. For many reasons I have to style the background of the svg root element through the style element, so for example I cannot add the style="background: blue" attribute to svg element or use javascript. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply the background style via `svg { ... }`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     version="1.1"
     width="100%" height="100%">
<style>
   svg {
      background: blue;
   }
</style>
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" fill="orange"/>
</svg>
```

*Note also: I've fixed your broken `<circle>` element.*

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the `<style>` to be embedded?

If not, just create two classes to style your svg, and use the CSS variable `currentColor` in your `<circle>` to be able to change its `fill` with the CSS `color` property.

> *Note:* Since SVG defines vector-based graphics in XML, you will need to
>   close your `<circle>` element with `/` .

---

```css
.svg__container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.svg__circle {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg__container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
  <circle class="svg__circle" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
```